# Openshift Pod Autoscaling

Tags: spring, kubernetes, openshift, autoscaling

We have Openshift cluster 3.11, where we have configured Horizontal Autoscaler:

```
Min Pods: 5 
Max Pods:10
Cpu Request Target: 80%
```

1) We have a spring application running in pods which persist data to mongodb. I have observed that when processing starts, it does increase pod count. However it also starts terminating pods when CPU utilization is less.

I have observed that when pods are terminated, it does not consider any processing running on that pod. Due to the same, i do find few database records are lost(records which were about to be saved from the pod which got terminated): mongodb collection count.

2) When i ran with fixed number of pods, i do not loose data.

Is there any way to tune Autoscaler so that it does not terminate pod , if there is any processing running ( for e.g async database save operations) on the pod

Or Terminate the pod only after particular duration even though the CPU utilization less?

Comment: Look at using a `preStop` hook to execute something in the container which delays shutdown until any required processing to flush out data is complete. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#termination-of-pods

Answer (score 0):

(quote) "...Or Terminate the pod only after particular duration even though the CPU utilization less?" - take a look at `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` in [PodSpec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#pod-v1-core).

If you are in control of the application and assuming a shell script kicks off the application, there may be some processing you can do in the shell script in response to SIGTERM (TERM signal) to handle graceful termination. See also [Termination of Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#termination-of-pods).